# how to do label.text = readKey in WFA

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I ensure that when you click on label, application expect to press any key, and when user press key, label text change to this key char?

Ok, now i have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool isLabelClicked = false;

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isLabelClicked = true;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLabelClicked)
        {
            label1.Text = ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();
            isLabelClicked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And if I press Up, Down, Left, Right, Tab or Enter, application not responding and still expects press key. Only when I press any other key, application works well.

If I create new project and paste the same code, all works well, for Up, Down, Left and Right also, but I need this keys for my application which I do.

Comment: Press any key while the hold the mouse button down? Or click (press and release) mouse button and then press any key? This is important.

Comment: click, not hold mouse button

Answer (score 1):

This example a textBox class : when press any key show it

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace KeyPressDisplayTextBox {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private Label label1;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(10,10);
        textBox1.KeyPress += textBox1_KeyPress;
        Controls.Add(textBox1);

        label1 = new Label();
        label1.Location = new Point(10, 40);
        label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 14);
        Controls.Add(label1);
    }

    void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        label1.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    }
 }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `KeyDown` event on the Form and get the `KeyValue` as below

Try This:

You need to set the Form `KeyPreview` property to `True` to receive the key events from the  `Form`

```
   bool isLabelClicked = false;

   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLabelClicked)
        {
            label1.Text = ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();
            isLabelClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isLabelClicked = true;
    }
```

Comment: it will always put the `key pressed` by user regardless of whether user `clicked on the label` or `not`.

Comment: Yes that is fine the in the particular case, but what if there are more than one label control? :p try to figure out.

Comment: @Iqbal: sorry i didnt get you , it works for one label only that is in my code `label1`.

Comment: I know that. And surely it will work if there is `label1` control on the form. I just twisted the question if there are two or more than one label. When user press 'label1' `keypressed` should go there after clicking on `label2` `keypressed` should go on `label2`.

Comment: @Iqbal: i have an answer to OP's question and no where he mentioned that he wants solution for multiple labels.

Comment: I have next problem. If I press up, down, left or right and tab or enter, application not responding. For any other key all is good. I don't need tab and enter, but up, down, left and right are necessary. Do you know how can I repair it?

Comment: @user3271955: i think it does not hang your UI. could you please edit your question with latest code?